# Tree diagram of a chess tournament amongst 4 players

Tags: probability, education, trees

I'd like to know which is the tree diagram of a chess tournament among 4 players. In particular, given 4 players A B C D, we know that there are the drawings of the players in order to create the couple of players. The 3 possibilities of drawing are (uniformly distributed so each of them has a probability of $1/3$):

$$
T_1: (A \, versus \, B) (C \, versus \, D) \\
T_2: (A \, versus \, C) (B \, versus \, D) \\
T_3: (A \, versus \, D) (B \, versus \, C)
$$

We know also that A is stronger than B, B is stronger than C, and C is stronger than D; in a challenge between 2 players, the stronger player has the win probability of $2/3$, the other player of $1/3$.

The **goal** is to get the win probability of C.
If I consider the first tournament $T_1$ (its drawing probability is $\color{red}{1/3}$), the win probability of C in the first challenge (C vs. D) is $\color{lightgreen}{2/3}$, instead the win probability of C in the second challenge (C vs. A or C vs. B) is $\color{orange}{1/3}$, so:

$$
P(C | T_1) = \color{red}{\frac{1}{3}} \color{lightgreen}{\frac{2}{3}} \color{orange}{\frac{1}{3}}
$$

**Tree diagram** of the above partial situation ($T_1$ tournament): what is the tree diagram?

[image]

Comment: What does $(A-B)(C-D)$ mean?

Comment: Hello @GerryMyerson it means that in the first tournament the first challenges are A vs. B and C vs. D. I will edit the question.

Comment: So are we playing three rounds, or just one?

Comment: @GerryMyerson there are 3 possible tournaments; each tournament is composed by 2 challenges.

Comment: So you are calling $T_i$ *tournaments* rather than *rounds* because the entire tournament is one round only? Also, what does $$
P(C | T_1) = \color{red}{\frac{1}{3}} \color{lightgreen}{\frac{2}{3}} \color{orange}{\frac{1}{3}}
$$ mean? I'm confused.

Comment: Hi @AdamRubinson I called T1 T2 T3 tournaments. Pay attention to the fact that we don't know a priori which is the real tournament, for this reason there is a probability associated to the tournaments Ti.

Comment: That doesn't answer my questions.

Comment: @AdamRubinson yes each match is composed by a single round (each tournament has 2 matches).

Comment: Now you're introducing the term "match" unnecessarily... But ok. And what about my second question please?

Comment: @AdamRubinson it's the win probability of C knowing that T1 occurred (maybe it's better the notation $P(C | \Omega \cap T_1)$ but we need also another event: the first winning in T1 which is not reported in the tree).

Comment: But surely that is $\frac{1}{3} \frac{2}{3}\ ?$ Why $\frac{1}{3} \frac{2}{3} \frac{1}{3} ?$

Comment: @AdamRubinson see the meaning of the colors in my question please

Comment: Sorry, I'm confused by it all. Also, the accepted answer said it's a knockout tournament which you failed to mention in your question (why?). Next time, please include all essential details in the question so as to not confuse readers...

Comment: @AdamRubinson ok sorry for the misunderstanding: each Ti is a knockout tournament

Comment: No, each $T_i$ is a *round* of a knockout tournament. For example, In $T_1,$ If $A$ wins his match against $B$ and $C$ wins his match against $D$, then who won the tournament $T_1$? No one has won yet...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming it is a knockout tournament.

From $T_1$ you need two branches, "$C$ wins" with probability $\frac{2}{3}$ and "$C$ loses" with probability $\frac{1}{3}$. From the end of the first of these you need another two branches, "$C$ wins" with probability $\frac{1}{3}$ and "$C$ loses" with probability $\frac{2}{3}$.

The probability of $C$ winning from $T_1$ is therefore $$\frac{2}{3}\times \frac{1}{3}=\frac{2}{9}.$$

Comment: Hello @S.Dolan thank you very much for your answer. We need also to put a $1/3$ because we have the probability to draw the couples defined in $T_1$ with probability $1/3$.

Comment: Yes. The answer I gave is for $C$ given $T_1$. For $T_1$ to occur and then for $C$ to win is indeed $\frac{2}{27}$ as you say.